# webpack output does not show in index.html

Tags: webpack

I am getting a blank html document. However, when I view the src code I am seeing my script tag that references dist/app.js which is my bundled code.

Here is my webpack and here is my index.html

Also, here is my folder structure.

```
/dist/app.js
/node_modules
/src/index.js
index.html
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    homepage: './src/index.js',
  },

  output: {
    filename: './dist/app.js'
  },

  // Resolve the `./src` directory so we can avoid writing
  // ../../styles/base.css
  resolve: {

    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },

  // Instruct webpack how to handle each file type that it might encounter
  module: {
    loaders:[
      { 
        test: /\.js[x]?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          ///plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
          presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        } 
      }
    ]
  },

  // This plugin moves all the CSS into a separate stylesheet
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
  ]
};

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="/dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you viewing the index.html file? Directly from hard disk or served via the development server?

Comment: Via the dev server. I am running npm start.

Comment: No errors in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry still cannot comment so I'll have to just answer.

My guess is the path is off by something maybe try throwing a dot in front of dist

```
<script src="./dist/app.js"></script>
```

Webpack is weird with paths and I'm a newb so I don't totally grasp all of it yet. But eventually you'll want cache busting and programmatically injecting your JS bundle into your index.html. Check out html-webpack-plugin. That plugin takes the main webpack chunk generates a copy of your index.html with the correct script tag.

I recommend https://survivejs.com/webpack/developing/getting-started/#setting-up-webpack-configuration for getting started with html-webpack-plugin